# How can I make the Add/Remove Programs list populate more quickly?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

I have a Windows XP Pro SP3 computer. The Add/Remove Programs window opens, but programs take about 50 minutes to load. This started when I downloaded Adobe X. The error message I'm getting says there is no memory.

How can I make the Add/Remove Programs list populate more quickly?

Comment: Can you edit your post to give more details on your machine (hard drive, CPU, memory etc.)

Comment: More system details would be very useful. I know XP can take a long time to load that list, but 50 minutes is *really* long.

Comment: Check that Windows Installer isn't corrupt. You may also have to troll through the Windows registry to find the location it is polling to look for problems there.

Comment: Uninstall Adobe X, see it it returns to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Should probably switch to [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). Much faster and more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

See what kind of results you get with a different uninstaller (front end).

Couple small ones to try:

"MyUninstaller v1.71 - Alternative to the standard add / remove control panel module"
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/myuninst.html

(don't know if this is viable for later OS's?)
"Safarp is a small and fast alternative to the Add or Remove Programs Control Panel applet of Windows 2000/XP"
http://wistinga.online.fr/safarp/

Oh, this too, http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=add+or+remove+programs+slow+to+open.

Comment: FWIW [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com) also has an Uninstall section in its Tools which I've noticed displays *much* faster than XP's native Add Or Remove Programs Control Panel. It's also a very useful utility in its own right.